# Troubleshooting SSH Access Denied Issue on Ubuntu Server 22.04.3

Tags: 22.04, ssh

Our team has successfully installed an Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS with the OpenSSH server package included. Post-installation, we ensured to adjust the SSH configuration to permit password-based authentication by setting `PasswordAuthentication yes` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, followed by a restart of the SSH daemon for the changes to take effect.

Subsequently, we attempted to establish an SSH connection using PuTTY. Despite entering the correct username and password, we encountered an "Access Denied" error. The server's `auth.log` reported a `pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure...` accompanied by a `Failed password for...` message.

We are seeking advice on potential resolutions to this issue. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Three typical culprits are 1) Different language settings so the keyboard characters are different, 2) User confusion; not really the set username/password after all, 3) User confusion; connecting to the wrong IP address (wrong machine). Your troubleshooting seems to have ruled out #3, but it might return if using DHCP.

Comment: @user535733 You are correct. It's keyboard problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue we encountered was eventually traced back to a keyboard-related problem with the VMware web console. Specifically, the discrepancy arose with the '@' character in our password, which was not being correctly interpreted as a genuine '@'. This realization led us to set a simpler password during the installation of the Ubuntu server, effectively resolving the problem.